# Android SQL Lite help: creating databasetable

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contract

I've been trying to reference the old code to create a table. I changed the key/column names for the new table and everything was working fine. However, when I tried to change the name from "expense" (from the old code) to "transaction" (new code). I got

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "transaction": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.cs465.groceryrun.groceryrun, PID: 7199
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cs465.groceryrun.groceryrun/com.cs465.groceryrun.groceryrun.Transactions}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "transaction": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title TEXT,person TEXT,role TEXT,date TEXT,due_date TEXT,status TEXT,rating REAL,amount REAL);
```

All I did was change the TABLE_NAME from:

```
 public static abstract class TransactionTable implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expense";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PERSON = "person";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ROLE = "role";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DUE_DATE = "due_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT = "amount";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COLUMN_NAME_TITLE    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_PERSON  + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_ROLE    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_DATE    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_DUE_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_STATUS  + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_RATING  + REAL_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT  + REAL_TYPE + ");";

    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
}
```

to:

```
public static abstract class TransactionTable implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "transaction"; //?????
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_PERSON = "person";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ROLE = "role";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DUE_DATE = "due_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT = "amount";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            COLUMN_NAME_TITLE    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_PERSON  + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_ROLE    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_DATE    + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_DUE_DATE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_STATUS  + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_RATING  + REAL_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_AMOUNT  + REAL_TYPE + ");";

    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

`transaction` is a [reserved keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) in SQL. Consider renaming your table to e.g. `transactions`.